# How to find a basis of a vector space by reference to a symmetric bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\ s: V \times V \to \mathbb R$ be a symmetric bilinear form defined by

\begin{equation}
\ s(x,y) = 3x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + 2x_3y_3 + x_1y_2 + x_2y_1 + 2x_2y_3 + 2x_3y_2,
\end{equation}

$\ V= \mathbb R^3$.

I want to find a basis $\ B = (b_1,b_2,b_3)$ of $\ V$ with $\ s(b_i,b_j) = \delta_{ij} \epsilon_i$, $\epsilon_i \in$ {-1,0,1}, $\ i,j = 1,2,3$.

I think I have to find vectors that are pairwise orthogonal, but how can I do that involving the equations and conditions above? (And is there at least one vector $\ v \in V$ that is not zero with $\ s(v,v) = 0$ anyway? Thanks for help.

Comment: By $ϵ_i∈ \{-1,0,1 \}$ do you mean $ϵ_1=-1, ϵ_2=0$ and $ϵ_3=1$ ?

Comment: No, I mean that e_1, e_2 and e_3 are either -1, 0 or 1 but that's not fixed yet.